# Axiom of Choice as a tool for proving measurability

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

We know that non measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$ exist, relative to the Lebesgue measure, but for finding one we need the Axiom of Choice. So I was thinking, maybe every time we need to prove measurability of a set, we could say that we didn't need the Axiom of Choice for constructing that set? For example, take two measurable functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. We know that $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) =g(x) \right\}$$  is measurable. Could we prove it just saying that we didn't use the Axiom of Choice to build that set?

Thanks for your answers.

**Edit**

To be more precise, my question is : if we make operations starting from some sets that are measurable or measurable functions, then we can conclude measurability just noticing that we haven't used the axiom of choice? (If we actually didn't)

Comment: No, it does not suffice to say you don't use choice to build it: given any two functions $f$ and $g$, measurable or not, you can build the given set without invoking the Axiom of Choice, but unless you know that $f$ and $g$ are measurable, you cannot deduce that the resulting set is measurable. Also note that being unable to prove a set is not measurable is not the same as proving it *is* measurable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin From the OP: " take two *measurable* functions" (emph. mine). And there is indeed a sense in which the answer to the OP's question is yes - I'm currently writing it - it's just quite difficult to do correctly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Right; the point is that measurability does not follow *merely* from the fact that we did not use the Axiom of Choice to construct the set, but rather from that *and* the properties of the two sets ($f$ and $g$) that we started with. Proving a set $X$ is not measurable requires the Axiom of Choice; that means that in the absence of Choice we are unable to prove that there exists a nonmeasurable set; but that does not mean we can prove all sets are measurable (that requires a *different* affirmative assumption, even under Solovay).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But the OP is taking the relevant properties of $f$ and $g$ as hypotheses already. So they're fine. (Well, modulo all the hard set theory ... :P)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: "Maybe **every time** we need to prove measurability of **a** set, we could say that we didn't need the [axiom of choice] for constructing that set." [emphasis added].

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Whoops, my bad, I managed to read "sometimes." Sorry! (Although arguably we only "need" to in cases where the relevant parameters are pretty concrete.)

Comment: Thank to you both. But, what i meant was, if we make operations starting from some sets that are measurable or measurable functions, then we can conclude measurability just noticing that we haven't used the axiom of choice?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211507/measurability-and-axiom-of-choice and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73902/axiom-of-choice-and-non-measurable-set

Comment: @astrobarrel If the question posted does not accurately reflect your meaning, then please edit the question so that it does; don't rely on people digging through comments to find your correction. And to avoid confusion with comments, please identify the changes as being changes (e.g, "(*Added:* what I mean is `blah`)")

Comment: If you start with a Lebesgue measurable set and apply a construction that doesn't involve the axiom of choice, the result may well not be Lebesgue measurable. For example, **every** subset of $\mathbb R$ can be obtained as the projection to the $x$-axis of a Lebesgue measurable (in fact measure-zero) subset of the plane.

Comment: I see. But you went "out" of the measure space. I think this is a little bit different and isn't really the point of the problem. Thanks for the observation, thought.

Comment: Also it is consistent with the usual axioms of set theory (ZFC) that there is a completely explicitly definable set of real numbers that is not Lebesgue measurable. (This happens, for example, in Gödel's constructible universe, with a $\Delta^1_2$ set.) On the other hand, it is consistent with ZFC that every explicitly definable set of real numbers is Lebesgue measurable, even if you allow arbitrary countable sequences of ordinals as parameters in the definitions. So the answer to the original question is it's undecidable.

Comment: Going "out of" the measure space was only for convenience. You can bring the example back to the same measure space by using the fact that there's a Lebesgue measure-preserving, Borel bijection between the plane and the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's definitely something along these lines we can do, but it's surprisingly difficult to do exactly: we need to talk about different "universes" in which our mathematics takes place, and how we can transfer facts between them appropriately. Unfortunately, the following answer is rather technical - that's sort of the point, that technical issues are essential here - but hopefully I've managed to pare things down to the point that it's actually interesting:

---

The key idea here is that of an **inner model** *(of ZF + whatever)*. The precise definition of the term is rather technical ("a transitive proper class satisfying the ZF axioms (+ whatever)"), but the intuition is that it's just a more restricted universe for doing math, which - by virtue of being more limited - might have nicer properties. (An inner model could also be much *worse* of course, but we're only going to be interested in the nice ones for now.)

Under reasonable set-theoretic assumptions (so-called "large cardinal hypotheses"), there are lots of inner models $M$ with the following properties:

- $M$ satisfies ZF + DC *(= a weak choice principle which prevents really stupid stuff from happening)* + "Every set of reals is measurable."
- Every real number is in $M$.
- If $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $X\in M$, then $X$ is measurable.

*(That third condition actually comes for free from the second, but that takes an argument.)* [We will call such models "nice."](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1097/8133)

The initial idea is that when we write a definition $\varphi$ of a set $S$ in the "real world," we can "copy" that definition in a nice inner model $M$ containing those parameters to get "$M$'s version of $\varphi$" - which I'll call "$\varphi^M$" - and by the niceness of $M$ conclude measurability of the original set.

### Unfortunately, we've got problems.

Our first issue is that our original definition $\varphi$ might involve some *parameters* - e.g. $\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}$ involves $f$ and $g$. Now we can't "run that definition inside $M$" unless $M$ also contains $f$ and $g$. So we can't use any old inner model.

Much worse, however, is the following: **when we switch from the "real world" to an inner model, definitions go wild**. For example, consider the definitions "$\{x: x\not=x\}$" and "$\{x:$ $x=17$ and the axiom of choice fails$\}$." In reality, these each correspond to the same set, namely the emptyset. But now suppose $M$ is a nice inner model. $\{x: x\not=x\}^M$ still defines $\emptyset$, but $\{x:$ $x=17$ and the axiom of choice fails$\}^M$ defines $\{17\}$ (since $M$ thinks the axiom of choice fails).

So here's what we need to do to make everything work. Suppose we have a definition $\varphi$ (using "parameters" $a_1,...,a_n$) of a set of reals $S$, and we want to show that $S$ is measurable.

- First, we show that $\varphi$ is **absolute**: if $M$ is any nice inner model and $r$ is a real number, then $M$ thinks $r$ is in the set defined by $\varphi$ iff $r$ really is in the set defined by $\varphi$. *(This isn't a given! Besides the toy example above, there are more serious examples: e.g. as Andreas mentions, it's possible that there is a fully-definable non-measurable set; so even if choice isn't involved explicitly in $\varphi$, "choiciness" could still play a hidden role.)*
- Next, we show that there is a nice inner model $M$ with $a_1,...,a_n\in M$. *(This also isn't a given! For a trivial example, suppose one of the parameters is itself a non-measurable set.)*

The second step lets me "run $\varphi$ inside $M$;" the resulting set of reals ("$M$'s version of $S$") is measurable, and by the first step that set is the actual $S$ we care about. We can also use this approach to prove "template" theorems, applying to many definitions at once.

However, all of this takes serious work, and relies on set-theoretic hypotheses beyond ZFC. The end result is:

> It takes a lot of work to make the argument you have in mind precise, let alone actually work, and ultimately requires more axioms than standard set theory actually uses.

---

Does that mean that "definition-examination" is never helpful to prove measurability?

**Not at all!** But we have to be more fine-grained in our examination, and look at the *syntactic complexity* of the definition: syntactic complexity is connected to *topological* complexity, and so we can sometimes argue that a set is measurable by saying something like: "The definition of this set has such-and-such syntactic form, so it's (say) Borel, and all Borel sets are measurable." This is part of *descriptive set theory*.

Comment: "Stupid stuff", or "weird stuff" (first bullet point)?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Hehe. For right now, stupid stuff. Stupid stuff I happen to *love*, but stupid nonetheless. (I'm using the term to emphasize the idea that $M$ is "lacking knowledge" about the real world - if $M$ were "smarter," then it would for example see that choice is actually true; the point being that despite $M$'s lack of knowledge, DC prevents $M$ from being *too* incorrect.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this awsome answer. I'm not sure  I got Every part of it, but I'm gonna read It again later. This kind of math looks really "weird" to Someone that Is not used to It, but Is fascinating too.